# firebase hosting folder is not created

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have completed the distribution along with the document.
However, there is no folder created in my project.

[image]

Below is my folder

[image]

Is there a problem with our setting?

Comment: I don't think that you are supposed to have a hosting folder but what I can see wrong is that you declared the public folder as public in the initialization. you should declare the build folder as the public one

Comment: I declared the build folder a public folder, but it's the same phenomenon.

Comment: I don't think that you are supposed to have a hosting folder because I have hosted my app on firebase and no hosting folder has been created. the only firebase related folders that I have are firebase.json that looks like this
```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

```
and hosting file in the .firebase folder which you can obtain by running npm run build if you are using npm

Comment: There is no folder related to firebase in my folder.
Is the initialization wrong?

Comment: Have you run the npm run build command (or yarn build if you're using Yarn)?
Make sure to add the configuration variable and initialize the app in the root component (typically App.js).
You can find the code for the configuration in the Firebase Analytics documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web
Additionally, ensure that you have installed all the necessary Firebase tools. Instead of just running npm install firebase, use npm install -g firebase-tools (or yarn add -g firebase-tools if you're using Yarn).